How to Unlink a Catalog from WhatsApp Business Account using Meta Graph API?

I'm trying to unlink a product catalog from a WhatsApp Business Account (WABA) via the Meta Graph API. Still, I can't find the appropriate API endpoint for this action.
From the Meta Business Manager, I noticed that when unlinking a catalog, the following request is made:
Request URL: https://business.facebook.com/api/graphql/
Request Method: POST
{
"input": {
"waba_id": "WABA_ID_HERE",
"catalog_id": "CATALOG_ID_HERE",
"action": "UNLINK",
"actor_id": "ACTOR_ID_HERE",
"client_mutation_id": ""
}
}
However, this seems to be part of the internal GraphQL API, and I can't find a corresponding endpoint in the official Graph API documentation to unlink a catalog from a WABA.
Is there a specific Graph API endpoint or another method that allows unlinking a product catalog from a WABA through the official Meta Graph API? If so, could you provide details on implementing it or any alternative solution?
Thank you in advance for any help!

I am also working on same, If you found any api or doc related to this then it will be helpful to us by sharing info

To unlink a product catalog from a WhatsApp Business Account (WABA) via the Meta Graph API, use the following DELETE request:
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/<WHATSAPP-BUSINESS-ID>/product_catalogs?catalog_id=<CATALOG-ID>&access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>'

Replace <WHATSAPP-BUSINESS-ID>, <CATALOG-ID> and <YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN> with your WABA ID, catalog ID, and a valid access token, respectively.
Required Permissions:
Ensure your access token includes both whatsapp_business_management and catalog_management permissions to successfully unlink the catalog.
